# Html Element properties in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

How do it create/access my own properties for elements in C# that I will use in JS.
    
and how do I access properties that are avaiable in Html but don't appear to be exposed in the c# set like the border property for tables 
    
I know I can do it with styles and classes, but it seems like a limp around as opposed to the most robust way to do it.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [`Attributes` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webcontrol.attributes.aspx) of the `WebControl` base class is what you're looking for.  Example:

```
MyControl.Attributes["myattr"] = "examplevalue";
```

Comment: Thank you so much.  That was it.  Any suggestions for the table attribute: border. C# wants to set it to 0 by default and changing the attribute only adds another border=1.

Comment: There's a BorderWidth property on the Table class.  Have you explored that property?

Answer (score 1):

The most robust as well as the most correct way of doing it is though CssClass property and a class defined inside a .css file.

One reason to this is that if you have a designer who only touches CSS, they can change styles without touching your C# source code. If you don't have a designated CSS person, layer separation is still beneficial - just imagine looking though source code to change border color.

Separating CSS, source code and JS as much as you can is the advisable practice.

Comment: Thanks for the larger picture considerations.  I will keep that in mind as I choose which to put where.

Comment: I'd like to add that you can always use JS and DOM to modify CSS styles inline on the fly.